# How to add static data in dynamic table view content. And perform calculation

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have one table view which will display the dynamic data of product name and its price and qty. What i need is , at last of all product showned in my table view. The total product can be any thing. Like 10 products or 2 product. What ever it may be. But at last of all product i have to show the 3 static data. Like  `SUBTOTAL, TAX, TOTAL`. And i need to calculate the product qty X prodct cost of all product. And in my sub total, tax, totla i need to display the total amount.

Like this :
[image]

And this is my table view code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartcel", for: indexPath) as! cartTableViewCe
cell.productName.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproName
cell.productQty.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproPrice
cell.productAmount.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproPrice
return cell;
} 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {       
 return self.Addtocartdata.count
}
```

Comment: What is difficult there?  just add 3 more rows statically that means in "numberOfRowsInSection" "return self.Addtocartdata.count + 3" as you know always you need these 3 rows. Then do the calculation by checking the last 3 row. Mention what problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: I dont know how to add the the static data . And to do the calculation . That have to calculate the all product qty x cost and have to display in my total .

Comment: @mack what is problem you face ? in this question

Comment: See actually , i want to add the 3 static name like sub total, tax, total. And its hsould be look like single table view. And i dont know how to perform the calculation for this . Like i need to calculate the qty x cost of all product and i need to display in my total cell of table view

Comment: @mack are you got a value of how many qty and tax price ? and how much sub total ?

Comment: Its will come from api. So it may be 10 or 2 . But after display the products from api. Tha next cell have to be the subtotal, tax, total. Like the image i have given in my post. And if i have 5 product. Then each product have qty and cost. So i have to calculate the each product qty x its cost. And i have to sum all product cost. And have to display in my total.

Comment: @mack just send me project that you updated it and put comment when you got your qty and tex price i will check it and give solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126719/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-mack).

Comment: @mack approve my this answer and give up vote. and your that problem solve now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i create one NSlayoutConstrain for tableview hight .

```
self.tableviewhightconstrain.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height // give value according to item


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.Addtocartdata.count == 0 {
            return 0
        }
        return self.Addtocartdata.count + 1
    }



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row < self.Addtocartdata.count {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartcel", for: indexPath) as! cartTableViewCell
                cell.productName.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproName
                cell.productQty.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproPrice
                cell.productAmount.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproPrice
                return cell;
            }
            else{ // here is second cell that i create ok.
                 var total11 : Double = 0.0
                let totalitem : Int = self.Addtocartdata.count as Int
                for item in 0...totalitem - 1 {
                    let subtotal = 0.0

                   total11 = subtotal +  Double(self.Addtocartdata[item].cartproPrice!)!

                }
                print(total11)
                let totalcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "totalcell", for: indexPath)
                let subtotal : UILabel = totalcell.viewWithTag(5) as! UILabel

                subtotal.text = "$ \(total11)"
                let tax : UILabel = totalcell.viewWithTag(6) as! UILabel
                tax.text = "$ 125" // here give your tax 
                let finaltotal : Double = total11 + 125 // also add that text value here

                let total : UILabel = totalcell.viewWithTag(7) as! UILabel
                 total.text = "$ \(finaltotal)"

                return totalcell

            }
  }



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row < Addtocartdata.count {
            return 70
        }else{
            return 134
        }
    }
```

Output :

[image]