# Objective-C : 2 different custom cells in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that contain 2 different custom cell. One is **ExerciseTime** and one is **RestTime**. I want my **RestTime** cell to be inserted between every 2 **ExerciseTime** cell :

[image: My TableView]

Here is my code:

-Height for row

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // RestTime
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
        return 40.0f;
    }

    // ExerciseTime
    else {
        return 65.0f;
    }
}
```

-Number of row in section (i couldnt find a way to set number of row for both **RestTime** and **ExerciseTime**)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (self.preset.blocks.count * 2) - 1;
}
```

-Cell for row

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
        RestTimeTableViewCell *restTimeCell = (RestTimeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RestTimeTableViewCellIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];
        RestTime *restTime = (RestTime *)[self.restTimeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //CustomCell
        return restTimeCell;
    }else{
        ExerciseTimeTableViewCell *exerciseTimecell = (ExerciseTimeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ExerciseTimeTableViewCellIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];
        ExerciseTime *exerciseTime = [self.exerciseTimeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //CustomCell
        return exerciseTimecell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

How can I create a tableView with 2 custom cell like this?

Comment: So what? What is your question?

Comment: Beside this, the number of rows is likely 2n-1.

Comment: @luk2302 I want my RestTime cell to be inserted between every 2 ExerciseTime cell

Comment: In your code the numberofRowsinSection method takes only the count of exerciseTime.

Comment: @Aneesh Yes i know that and i fixed it ,thanks

Comment: @VMCuongOnStackOverflow so your current output is been shown in your screenshot., right?

Comment: @Aneesh no,that only a design that i want to achive

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40261293/6656894 refer this tableview answer i just use 2 cell in single tableview

Comment: @VMCuongOnStackOverflow in your question you have mentioned like, " I want my RestTime cell to be inserted between every 2 ExerciseTime cell ". and in your image you have done something different.

Comment: @Aneesh You can assume that the Prep-time in the screenshot is RestTime cell and other cells is ExerciseTime

Comment: Don't expect complete app designed by SO . Do correct things and follow what others say . Don't ask question y i cannot use this and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First return count as total of two array in `numberOfRowsInSection` and then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` try some thing like this.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // RestTime
    if (indexPath.row % 3 == 0) {
        return 40.0f;
    }
    // ExerciseTime
    else {
        return 65.0f;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (indexPath.row % 3 == 0) {
        RestTimeTableViewCell *restTimeCell = (RestTimeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RestTimeTableViewCellIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //Access you object from array like this
        NSInteger index = (NSInteger) (indexPath.row / 3);
        RestTime *restTime = (RestTime *)[self.restTimeArray objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    else {
        ExerciseTimeTableViewCell *exerciseTimecell = (ExerciseTimeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ExerciseTimeTableViewCellIdentifier  forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //Access you object from array like this
        NSInteger index = (indexPath.row - (NSInteger) (indexPath.row / 3));
        ExerciseTime *exerciseTime = [self.exerciseTimeArray objectAtIndex:(index - 1)];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

**Output:** I have try this by setting background color as ***Red color*** for `RestTimeTableViewCell` and ***Green color*** for `ExerciseTimeTableViewCell`.

[image]

Comment: Can i ask why you use indexPath.row % 3 == 0 ? because i need my RestTime cell in odd indexPath(1,3,5,7,9,...) and ExerciseTime cell in even indexPath (0,2,4,6,8,...)

Comment: @VMCuongOnStackOverflow In question you have tell that, **I want my RestTime cell to be inserted between every 2 ExerciseTime cell**, that is the reason i have use `% 3` modular.

Comment: I have try to implement your code and i crash because "index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]"

Comment: i have edited answer please check once again.

Comment: i did it base on your code ,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if you have n exerciseTime, you will be able to insert n-1 restTimes. So

Try this...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.exerciseTime.count + (self.restTime.count >= self.exerciseTime.count) ? self.exerciseTime.count-1 : self.restTime.count;
}
```

Now, add exerciseTime in even position, and add restTime in odd position until current index exists in both of those lists. if current index exceeds restTime, then continue adding exerciseTime. Let me know if that works.

Comment: why negative? please enlighten me.

Comment: Thank you but that only solve 1 of my problem,can you help me on this

Comment: @UjjalSuttraDhar you really should not try to answer posts like this which do not even ask a question in the first place. You can only lose that way. Wait for clarification by OP or just walk away.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @UjjalSuttraDhar i think we just need (N * 2) -1 but thanks

Comment: What if you have 10 exerciseTime and 5 restTime in the list? Your code shouldn't assume that there always will be 10 exercise and 10 resttime, Right? Whatever, You can try with (self.exerciseTime.count * 2) - 1. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @UjjalSuttraDhar Yes it does. Thank for your help i would upvote your answer if i can

Comment: So, please think thousand time before doing any negative thing in future. Thanks anyway