# UITableView does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Question 1)**

I've spent a few hours trying to figure out this problem, from what I've read those are the two functions needed to implement the UITableView but it still gives me the error in the title:

```
import UIKit

class UITableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
{

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {

        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {


    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

    }

}
```

**Question 2)**

The TableView is a part of a tabbed view controller that I am implementing for my app. I want my TableView controller to have entries that once pressed will open another ViewController. How can I implement something like that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you working with Swift 3?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40261293/6656894 refer this answer

Comment: are you using storyboard ?

Comment: Why do you named your controller as the class name UITableView?

Comment: dont assign the class name `class UITableView: UIViewController` same as element name `UITableView` change your class name and add `tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self` at the same time check once your outlet is connected or not of current class

Comment: Yes I am using swift 3, I'm sorry I didn't include that in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrectly set up your ViewController. Either create a UITableViewController which is just a UITableView, or add a UITableView to a UIViewController (Like you have almost done).
The didSelectRowAt method will allow you to segue to a new viewController, but in my examples only if it is set up correctly in a storyboard.
**UITableViewController option**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell
}

// MARK: - Table view delegate

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

**UIViewController option**
 (The UITableView will need to be added through a Storyboard in this example)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell
}

// MARK: - Table view delegate

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

[Here is an example project to work from](https://github.com/MetzoPaino/TableViewTest)

Comment: Class ViewController should implement UIViewController, not UITableViewController

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I went with the second solution that you posted however for some reason I still can't link my TabView controller from the story board to this class. When I change the number of rows and run the app, nothing happens. I am sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: When I create cells and try to link them to my class using the control + drag feature it doesn't do anything. I am not sure what's causing this.

Comment: @KareemAboughazala I have added a link to a GitHub project at the end. Hopefully downloading that will clear some things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `UITableView` to manage the data source. That should be the job of `UITableViewController` which manages data to be displayed on `UITableView`. The `View` in general should only worry about how to display the data, not manage it. See [MVC design pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) by Apple.

Apple has a really nice, and complete [Swift App tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW1) (See Display the Data) that goes through how to set up `UITableViewController` with a table view you built with storyboard. You can also download and run the source project at the end of the page. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to to Implement This Mendatory  DataSource Method

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: downvoters mention the mistake and assign the downvote , it is useful for correct the mistake

Comment: How does this help in any way? What do you think the problem is here?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the mistake is hard to put into words because the answer given shows little understanding of what the actual question is and completely misses the blatantly obvious problem in it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I tried copying this function but the error is still there, now there is another error inside the function "value of type UITableView has no member dequeueReusableCell. I also noticed that I can't create an outlet from my tableView to my UITableView class using the control + drag feature. does this mean anything?